# Fk in different schemas, is it a good practice?

Tags: oracle

I have a Fk from let's say schema s1.table1 to schema s2.table1 in oracle, I just wondering if that is a good practice. I saw that, and that can solve part of my problem, which is, in schema s1 I have my main data store model, but y schema s2, I have a common data store model. So please give some guidence about how would be the best practice solving that kind of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is fine to do that. Ideally you will document this so that other users of the schemas are aware.  But don't go overboard and create a spaghetti of references like:

```
S1.TABLE1 references S2.TABLE2
S2.TABLE3 references S1.TABLE4
S3.TABLE5 references S1.TABLE6
S3.TABLE7 references S2.TABLE8
...
```

That way madness lies!  But a common schema makes sense:

```
S1.TABLE1 references S2.TABLE2
S1.TABLE3 references S2.TABLE4
S3.TABLE5 references S2.TABLE6
S3.TABLE7 references S2.TABLE8
```